# Swing updating UI components while the job is running

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

I am developing a swing applciation. In that I have a workflow of jobs to be done.

I Am running these jobs in a for loop one after the other. The interesting thing is I have to update GUI status bar with the current job name running.

I can not use SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait as it can not run on the dispatch thread which will be the currently running thread.

I tried using SwingWorker since the jobs are running in a loop, the SwingWorker's doBackGrount() method will execute and will come out and gets the the next index to run the next job. In the done() of SwingWorker I have written code to update GUI with the status.

```
public class TestAction extends SwingWorker<Boolean, Void> {

    boolean executeThread = false;

    public TestAction() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {
        executeThread = ExecuteWebServiceAction.webServiceExecution();
        return executeThread;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        try {
            boolean isOver = (boolean) get();
            if (isOver) {
                MainApplication.getInstance().getFrame().setStatus(LangUtil.getString("cdsExecuteFinehed")
                        + " " + ((WebServiceTool) DrawingManager.getInstance().getCurrentTool()).getName());
                FrameMain.jPanel6.repaint();
            }
        } catch (Interr`enter code here`uptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestAction.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestAction.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is where am calling TestAction:

```
if (!WorkFlow.isIsWorkflow()) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
      new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          webServiceExecution();
        }
    });
} else {
     new TestAction().execute();
}
```

Comment: The SwingWorker approach makes sense - what is the problem with it? It also has a `getProgress()` method to help you track the progress of a task (not sure if you need this).

Comment: *"Am running outta time"*  So hire a consultant & pay them fees to match your urgency.

Comment: please edit question with your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: "Am running outta time" am sorry for that,,,:(

Comment: The problem is after the doBackGround() method is invoked....immediately my next job is running and then the done() method is invoked....What I want is to execute doBackGround() and then done() method, update UI Coponent,then go to next job....but its not happening

Comment: @user1249469 If you don't post your code (the relevant parts) it is difficult to help you.

Comment: OK here it is....the swingworker class

Comment: @assylias ...how to paste the code in comment box as am new to this

Comment: @user1249469 don't post it in a comment, add it to your question. You need to insert 4 spaces at the beginning of each line to get proper formatting.

Comment: @assylias..Thank u so much i have just updated my qiuestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000); in SwingWorker's doInBackground method before currentthread finishes its execution and update your UI

Answer (score 3):

> running in a loop one after the other and notify UI when one is done

sounds like "big job with intermediate results". Intermediate results are supported via the publish/process methods:

- implement doInBackground to loop through the jobs and call publish when one is terminated
- implement process to do the ui update

Answer (score 0):

You could add a Runnable to your constructor to be run when done() is over:

```
public class TestAction extends SwingWorker<Boolean, Void> {

    boolean executeThread = false;
    private final Runnable runWhenDone;

    public TestAction(Runnable runWhenDone) {
        this.runWhenDone = runWhenDone;
    }

    //...

    @Override
    protected void done() {
    try {
        boolean isOver = (boolean) get();
        if (isOver) {
            MainApplication.getInstance().getFrame().setStatus(LangUtil.getString("cdsExecuteFinehed")
                + " " + ((WebServiceTool) DrawingManager.getInstance().getCurrentTool()).getName());

            //Run the Runnable here
            runWhenDone.run();

            //...
```

And in your GUI class

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {public void run() {updateTheTitle();}};
(new TestAction(r)).execute();
private void updateTheTitle() { yourTitle.setText("I am done");}
```

Comment: do I have to create the method called runWhenDone() in TestAction?

Comment: Is your TestAction class an inner class to your GUI class or is it in a separate file?

Comment: If TestAction is in a separate file, you need to create the Runnable in your GUI (cf the bottom of my answer). The `updateTheTitle` method, which you need to implement in your GUI class to update whatever needs to be updated, will be called when the SwingWorker is done.

Comment: I have done what you said but in TestAction under done() method...runWhenDone() is not created right?

Comment: So wht i understand is under done()...I just have to add runWhenDone.run();....am I correct...

Comment: @user1249469 yes - sorry for the typo

Comment: not a problem....but still the problem exists ....the done() is executing at the end of for loop...

Comment: @user1249469 I probably misunderstood your question then - there is no for loop in your code. If all the tasks are executed at once, you could use one SwingWorker for each, so that done() would be executed at the end of each task, or you could add a propery called "executedTask" for example, and call the `firePropertyChange("executedTask",previousTaskName,"Task x")` method when a task is done. In your GUI you can register a listener to those changes which will execute your title update with the right task name...

Comment: can you give on example for the property change please